# QuickBooks rounding issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

We are primarily Sage developers and I have been able to achieve this in Sage. Now I need the same functionality in QB and we are struggling. The problem is a rounding issue. We have a spreadsheet with Gross (total) invoice amount. We take that data, calculate NET and VAT and post it to QB 2014 using SDK v13. But we have a problem when for example the total is £123.45, the NET (before tax) should be £102.88 and the VAT (tax) should be £20.57, but QB is calculating VAT at 20% as £20.58 giving us a total of £123.46, which is incorrect in terms of what we want the value to be.

We are using IInvoiceAdd and IORInvoiceLineAdd in order to add invoice into QB. How can we achieve the above and tell QB that the total VAT is £20.57 and not £20.58, by keeping the accountants happy? Any adjustment to NET or adding adjustment item or doing journal entries are work-arounds rather than a fix, we want to know if this is possible as we did in Sage. We are able to do this via the UI in QB, so is there a code equivalence to do this.

Comment: The tags specify QBO but your method names look like QB Desktop. Which are you on?

Comment: I am on the QB Desktop Matthew and I have modified the tags, thanks. What William has suggested doesn't work and I am not sure HMRC are going to be happy with this. So for the time being, we are making do by telling the user that there is an issue for a certain amount in the Excel file we import and then they can change tax manually in QB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QB cannot do this at the moment via the API, there are workarounds, but we thought it would be best to notify the customer about the error and let them fix it in UI, rather than play around with zeroing the VAT or changing VAT rate to suit the need.

Answer (score 0):

You will set the invoice sales tax to a zero tax, so no tax is calculated.

You will add each invoice line as normal, but you want to make sure no tax is calculated here as well.

You will add one more line item for the tax and this would be where you enter the tax you want.

Comment: Thank you William - but then will the VAT column be populated?

Comment: Sorry William, this doesn't work. I am not sure HMRC or the accountant will be happy with this work-around. If a item is VATable then it needs to be marked and shown as VATable and the VAT column on the invoice needs to be populated for it to be a valid VAT invoice. So basically you are telling us that Sage can do this but QB can only achieve this in UI and not by code.